Remote Oracle Apex with Local C# Node
I have an Oracle Apex (v23.2) application running on a remote VPS that needs to sign documents before submitting them. The signing process has to be done with a USB Token, which means the signing program can only run on a local PC. The signing program is written in C#. What would be the best way/design to communicate between the Apex Application and the signing program without any security issues? and is there a guide for it?
A few of the ideas I found: First, to use a middleware server to control the sending and receiving between the Apex application and the signing program, such as RabbitMQ. However, not so many guides for Oracle Apex and RabbitMQ. Second, to implement a WebSockets server on the signing program node. However, how would I be able to reach the local node securely?
Is there a better approach? If so, what is it, and how to implement it?
